# Capistrano - mark deployment as failed

Tags: deployment, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano 3.

I want to trigger a webhook to a external service, when my deployment fails.

It's a matter of calling a method I have already defined, let's say it's called `mark_failed`.

**How I can ensure the method is always called when the deployment fails, for whatever reason, except aborting it via CTRL+C ?**

Tried fiddling around with

`rescue SystemExit, Interrupt` and `rescue StandardError`

I have no clue where to put my method call the way it will be called reliably.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `at_exit`.

```
at_exit do
   mark_failed if $!
end
raise "Something is wrong!"
```